# Social network with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

My project is social network website which will be built on CMS. I have decided for WordPress. The thing is I am not so sure about my decision now.

Website should have features like login and register forms, profile making and editing, user generated content from front end of site, content making restriction only on registered users of website, publishing most popular posts on home page.

User posts should be public. What I mean by that is, while I was previewing themes, I noticed that most posts from users were posted in groups. I would like this website to work more like Facebook.

Is it possible to make this sort of website with WordPress without custom plugins? And could you recommend a theme for this sort of project?

Sorry for long question and thanks in advance :D

Comment: This is StackOverflow not Quora :)

Answer (score -1):

You should look into Social specific plugin/project for WordPress called BuddyPress. https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/

If you look into buddypress specific themes you might be able to find something which is similar to your goals.

Here is official website https://buddypress.org/ (it is open source free project by WP team)

It has a feature called Activity Stream which you might be looking for which is like FB timeline.